# Make "default" text to appear in an empty TextBox without focus using XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to create a TextBox, which would have a gray "default" text appear in it, if it's

a) empty

b) has lost focus

when the user enters the text box, the gray "default" text should dissappear.

I've tried to do this using `ControlTemplate.Triggers`, but I can't seem to find `HasFocus` property.

What is the best way to do this using XAML?

Comment: I'd agree with @Fuji and suggest the `WatermarkTextBox`, but for future reference the `HasFocus` equivalent is `IsKeyboardFocused` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.iskeyboardfocused.aspx

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Whilst there is no real benefit in re-inventing the wheel, it might be interesting to see how this can be done.  The easiest way to do this (in pure XAML) is to create a `ControlTemplate` for the `TextBox` that overlays a `TextBlock` when it is not focussed and does not contain text:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Text="Your Prompt Here"
                Margin="5,0,5,0"
                Foreground="#FF808080"
                FontStyle="Italic"
                IsHitTestVisible="False"
                x:Name="UserMessage"
                Visibility="Hidden"/>
</Grid>
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Property="Text" Value=""/>
            <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="False"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="UserMessage" Value="Visible"/>
    </MultiTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The `MultiTrigger` means "set Visibility to Visible if the `Text` property is empty AND the TextBox does not have keyboard focus"

If you want to make this more reusable then you could create a custom control with this as it's default template and with a Dependency Property containing the prompt message

Comment: I agree pure XAML is nice if used rarely in a simple application. I hate adding 3rd party dlls to projects unless used frequently.

Comment: @fuji and its good to understand how these things actually work!

Comment: @SteveGreatrex how do I create a custom control for different text for example Text="Your Prompt Here" , another text box I need the text to be "You Prompt There" .

Answer (score 14):

You could simply use the [Extended WPF Toolkit](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit)'s [WatermarkTextBox](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/WatermarkTextBox).
[image]

I wrote a small guide based on your comment on how you to add and use the library in your project.

**Step 1)** Right-click on `References` in your project and choose `Add Reference`.

[image: Step 1]

**Step 2)** Locate and add the dll file `WPFToolkit.Extended.dll`.

[image: Step 2]

**Step 3)** Last you need to add the `XAML` code.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:extToolkit="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <extToolkit:WatermarkTextBox Watermark="Enter First Name" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The key here is to add the `reference` to the dll file.

```
xmlns:extToolkit="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
```

Then you can simply use it in `XAML` like this.

```
<extToolkit:WatermarkTextBox Watermark="Enter First Name" />
```

Comment: It's a custom library that you download from the site I linked you. http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/84227

Comment: yeah, I did that. But I'll have to reference it to get the watermark textbox. There are several assemblies in that library. Which one should I reference?

Comment: There is only one dll file in the zip file `ExtendedWPFToolkit_Binaries.zip`, it should contain a dll file named `WPFToolkit.Extended.dll` that you add as a `Reference` in `Visual Studio`.

Comment: ah. I've confused it with wpf toolkit. Thanks!

Comment: np, glad you found a solution. ;)

Comment: This is ok but the library is only free if you got less then 10 Users.