# Putting default text in a password box in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, passwordbox

I'm creating a login page using visual studio 2012 for windows 8 apps. I'm adding a username and password box, as expected, but instead of putting text beside the boxes to show what each is for, I want to write it within the box, as done in this picture: http://www.windows8designhandbook.com/img/gallery/nasdaq/nasdaq_splash_login.png

How do I get the default text in there? I'm using a textbox for the userID and a passwordbox for the password.

Comment: And what type of project are you building for Windows 8? Silverlight or HTML? Windows application?

Comment: Windows Application. I'm working with the .xaml files

Comment: If its a XAML application, the answer was given in this post: [Make “default” text to appear in an empty TextBox without focus using XAML][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428230/make-default-text-to-appear-in-an-empty-textbox-without-focus-using-xaml

Comment: @RichardSeal But that solution uses a text box. I was hoping to be able to do it with a password box.

Comment: Yes, but the principles should still apply. You are still trying to create a watermark.

Comment: Please post answers as answers (do not insert answers into your question... it is confusing for other users in the long run)

Comment: @Richard - Unfortunately, the principle does not apply to password textboxes as they will obfuscate the prompt text (***). You must modify the behavior or visual tree of the password box. The article the OP found is more appropriate then the linked Q/A.

Comment: Tolu - The last link in the accepted answer of @Michael's duplicate question should cover you, and seems to be a lot easier then the example you found.

Answer (score 0):

The OP included the following in an update to his question:

> I think I've found an answer: http://julmar.com/blog/mark/?p=300

The linked article contains the following summary in the opening paragraph:

> In the previous post, I wrote about a Blend behavior for Windows Store apps to add a watermark to a TextBox.  The next question I got was “Well, what about a PasswordBox?” PasswordBox is a bit tricker since it doesn’t allow text to be displayed in the clear – so our little trick of changing the Text property doesn’t work here.  So, instead, let’s get a little hacky (or clever depending on how you look at it I suppose).  We can use the same series of events (GotFocus/LostFocus/Loaded) but instead of changing text, let’s add a new TextBlock into the visual tree of the PasswordBox to display our watermark text.

**Article**: [Adding a watermark to a PasswordBox in a Windows Store app](http://julmar.com/blog/mark/?p=300)
**Blog**: [Wandering through the wilderness: *Exploring the world of .NET 4.0, iOS, WPF, MVVM and other cool technologies*](http://julmar.com/blog/mark/)

A similar question, [Create WPF Watermark in Pure XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687596/create-wpf-watermark-in-pure-xaml), contains a link to a Code Project article, [A WatermarkTextBox in 3 lines of XAML](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26977/A-WatermarkTextBox-in-3-lines-of-XAML), which proposes a solution that should work equally well for a regular textbox or a password textbox:

> ```
> <Grid Background="{StaticResource brushWatermarkBackground}">
>     <TextBlock Margin="5,2"
>                Text="Prompt..."
>                Foreground="{StaticResource brushForeground}"
>                Visibility="{Binding ElementName=txtUserEntry, 
>                                     Path=Text.IsEmpty,
>                                     Converter={StaticResource
>                                         BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
>     <TextBox Name="txtUserEntry"
>              Background="Transparent"
>              BorderBrush="{StaticResource brushBorder}" />
> </Grid>
> ```